# skalable signpost with html, css and SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to make a button in the form of a signpost (rectangle with tip).

```
 _______
|       \
|_______/
```

I want to dynamically write text into the sign, each with different lengths.
If I try this only with a graphic as background graphic, the arrowhead is scaled with and compressed / stretched accordingly.
Therefore the approach to put the text in a normal div and attach the arrowhead as SVG using CSS :after.
The arrow should be fully filled, i.e. I don't have to deal with frame problems. (To increase the visibility I left the SVG black)
My first problem is that the arrowhead is always in the block instead of behind it. this I solved with position:absolute;. But further fine tuning fails, because I can't position based on the end of the block with left: and right:
Questions:

- How do I have to position so that the triangle always connects exactly to the end of the box. (no white betwwen)
- How can I scale the SVG with the size (height) of the box. (So that the edges fits) (maybe also with consideration of the paddings of the )

Or am I completely on the wrong track with the approach via :after and should rather append the arrow (as SVG file) direkt in the HTML behind the text (text ay enclose  with ) and enclose all with the ? But actually I wanted to avoid that, the insert via CSS would be nicer. But if that is the more useful way, I can live with it.

```css
.querverweis{
    background-color: #005000;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px  
     margin-left: -10px 
}

.querverweis:after {
  content:  url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' width='32' height='40' viewBox='0 0 66 100' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0 L66 50 L0 100 L0 0' style='fill=rgb(0,0,0)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");   
  position: absolute; 
}
```

```html
<div class="querverweis">Test</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the 'signpost' to be a solid color (you have the main part with a sort of green in your given code). If so, clip-path rather than trying to append an svg might be simpler.

Comment: yes, should be solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As A Haworth mentions, clip-path might be simpler. To do this, add some `padding` to the right of the button to always have space where the arrow will live and then `clip-path` the whole element

```css
.querverweis {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #005000;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - 1rem) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 1rem) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="querverweis">Test</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="querverweis">Test with more text</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="querverweis" style="max-width:6rem">Test with multi-line text</div>
```

Comment: Great! Exaclty what I'm looking for!